# NSIS - See if a given process has shown a window

Tags: windows, user-interface, process, nsis

I run a certain process via ExecShell from my NSIS installer. That process takes sometime to start (5 - 40 seconds maybe), during which I want the NSIS window to remain visible.

The problem is that while the process itself starts almost instantly, it is sometime before a user would see anything, thus I want the NSIS installer window to remain visible UNTIL the started process's main window (or any window for that matter is shown).

What I need to know thus is how do I get processid from ExecShell (can't use Exec or ExecWait for other reasons), and then how do I use that process id to see if the window has been shown (I know I can do it via a simple sleep, check, goto loop, so basically I am trying to figure out the check part of it)?

So, how exactly can I know if the process I spawned using ShellExec has shown a GUI. This needs to work in Windows XP SP3 and up.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you require ExecShell and not a plain Exec? Are you starting a .exe or a non-executable file type?

Comment: Different user permissions. My installer is non-admin by default. Whereas the program to be started may or may not require admin rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RequestExecutionLevel user
Page InstFiles

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh ; For SW_*

Var IsSlowFakeApp ; We can also pretend to be a silly little app that is slow to start up, this is just so the example code has no external dependencies

Function .onInit
StrCpy $0 $CMDLINE 1 -1
${If} $0 == "?"
    StrCpy $IsSlowFakeApp 1
    Sleep 3333
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd


Function StartMyAppAndWaitForWindow
StrCpy $0 "$ExePath" ; Application
StrCpy $1 "?" ; Parameters
!define SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS 0x40
DetailPrint 'Starting "$0" $1'
System::Store S
System::Call '*(i60,i${SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS},i$hwndparent,i0,tr0,tr1,i0,i${SW_SHOW},i,i,i,i,i,i,i)i.r0'
System::Call 'SHELL32::ShellExecuteEx(ir0)i.r1'
${If} $1 <> 0
    System::Call '*$0(i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i.r1)'
    System::Call 'USER32::WaitForInputIdle(ir1,2000)i'

    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetProcessId(ir1)i.r2' ; MSDN says this function is XP.SP1+
    StrCpy $3 $2 ; Not found a window yet, keep looping

    ; Call EnumWindows until we find a window matching our target process id in $2
    System::Get '(i.r5, i) iss'
    Pop $R0
    callEnumWindows:
        System::Call 'USER32::EnumWindows(k R0, i) i.s'
        loopEnumWindows:
            Pop $4
            StrCmp $4 "callback1" 0 doneEnumWindows
            System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowThreadProcessId(ir5,*i0r4)'
            ${If} $4 = $2
                System::Call 'USER32::IsWindowVisible(ir5)i.r4'
                ${IfThen} $4 <> 0 ${|} StrCpy $3 0 ${|} ; Found a visible Window
            ${EndIf}
            Push $3 ; EnumWindows callback's return value
            System::Call "$R0"
            Goto loopEnumWindows
        doneEnumWindows:
    ${If} $3 <> 0
        Sleep 1000
        Goto callEnumWindows
    ${EndIf}
    System::Free $R0

    ; Hide installer while app runs
    /*HideWindow
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::WaitForSingleObject(ir1,i-1)'
    BringToFront*/
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::CloseHandle(ir1)'
${EndIf}
System::Free $0
System::Store L
FunctionEnd

Section
${If} $IsSlowFakeApp <> 0
    SetCtlColors $HWNDPARENT 0xffffff 0xdd0000
    FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    SetCtlColors $0 0xffffff 0xdd0000
    DetailPrint "This is a fake slow app and it will close soon..."
    Sleep 5555
    Quit
${Else}
    Call StartMyAppAndWaitForWindow
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work if you elevate the child process with UAC. I don't believe MSDN documents which access rights you have to a child processes elevated with UAC.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick answer. It seems to be kind of working, except there is still a 5-10 second delay between installer hiding itself (because it has found a window) and the actual window of the app appearing on the screen. Any idea why? Might it be possible to add a filter, i.e. like window.classname.startswith("WinForms...")?

Comment: Also, I see that you are effectively using something similar to ExecWait but using Shell. What if I want to just launch the app, do the window stuff, and then continue with some other installer logic w/o waiting for the app to quit (i.e. w/o WaitForSingleObject stuff)?

Comment: You don't need HideWindow+WaitForSingleObject+BringToFront but you have to call ShellExecuteEx directly so you can get the process handle. I'll update the loop with a call to check if the window is visible...

Comment: Thank you for the update. Though it still did not work for me, as there was almost a 10 second delay between window actually being visible on the screen and installer being hidden. I realize this is tricky, so I will need to think of some other way to get the actual status of the window.

Comment: A naive question from someone who never used System::Call in NSIS: How safe is it, in a sense of installer crashing or running into problems, and with this particular code, should I be aware of anything using it with Unicode vs Non-Unicode NSIS?

Comment: Please disregard my comment before the previous one - it works like a charm! Thank you! (For some reason I can't edit or remove the old comment) Just a quick question though: Why when I add "StrCpy $5 0" somewhere before the main routine and then add "IntOp $5 $5 + 1" followed by "IntCmp $5 60 hideanyway callEnumWindows hideanyway" between "Sleep 1000" and "Goto callEnumWindows", installer hides prematurely (but way sooner than the 60 seconds). With this I basically want to force hiding after 1 minute.

Comment: $5 (r5) is already in use, use $6. This System code should work as  Ansi and Unicode but it will not work with 64-bit NSIS! (Some 'i's would need to become 'p's and the struct size is not 60 on x64)

Comment: Thanks so much! Though this is not directly related to my original question, since you are NSIS expert, I was wondering if these 2 would be possible while waiting for the app to show: 1) change style of installer progress bar to marque (continuous "scrolling"); 2) replace or overlay in some way the details area with a picture (png or bitmap included with the installer) - the idea being to show something more meaningful and useful to the user whil he/she waits for the app to start?

Comment: I'm guessing it would be possible but you should probably ask it in a new question...

Comment: You're right... just did it. Once again big thank you for all your help!

Comment: Sorry, a question came up: if the app to be launched requires admin rights, the installer is running as a standard user, how do I know if a user agreed to UAC prompt (and the app was started), or he denied UAC prompt (and app was never started). How do I capture that info so I can follow up with logic later in case the user did not confirm UAC prompt?

Comment: @FitDev: This is not easy to answer but I assume you are using the runas verb. On XP you can use any user in the dialog including yourself with _less_ privileges. On Vista+ if UAC is turned off it will just start the process normally with no warnings. In both cases you will end up with a process handle that you would have to inspect...

Comment: Thanks for getting back! I am actually using your code above. In particular, the app is run with "System::Call 'SHELL32::ShellExecuteEx(ir0)i.r1'". All I really want to know is that in case of UAC prompt, if the user allowed execution (and process was created) or the user did not allow execution (no process was created and ran). I am simply not sure how to do it from the code above. That is where the return value from ShellExecuteEx System Call would be stored and how to access/interpret it before "System::Free $0" line?

Comment: @FitDev: I thought you wanted to force elevation. Anyway, if you change one line to `System::Call 'SHELL32::ShellExecuteEx(ir0)i.r1 ?e'` and add two lines: `Pop $2` and `DetailPrint "Return=$1, GetLastError=$2"` then $1 will be 0 and $2 will be 1223 (ERROR_CANCELLED) when you cancel the UAC dialog.